# How to access top level package in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, global

I would like to access an [ActionScript 3.0 top level function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html) from a class of mine, in which a symbol with the same name (`trace`) as the top level function is already defined:

```
class A {
  public static function trace():void {
  }
  trace("Test");
}
```

I would like to call the global ActionScript `trace` function with `trace("Test")`, but this is not possible as another symbol `function trace()` is defined.

In a case where the external definition which I would like to access would be located in a package (`flash.utils` or so), I could access that external definition with `flash.utils.[definitionName]`, as I do here with ByteArray:

```
import flash.utils.*;
class ByteArray {
  var data:flash.utils.ByteArray;
}
```

Is there a similar syntactical expression in ActionScript 3.0 that would allow me to access the trace function in the first example without changing the name of my class method `trace`?

This is a hypothetical question, please do not consider workarounds. I need to solve the problem exactly as asked above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there is something you're leaving out. As your code is posted, you would have to have an instance of A to call trace on, which would not interfere with calling the Flash trace function. You sure your trace method isn't static?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`trace` is in the `public` namespace so it could be reached calling `public::trace` , however here the problem is that you are redefining another **public** trace, so you can't call the previous one.

*What you can do is :*

1 - if your method trace have not to be `public` made it `protected or private` and then you will be able to call the original trace:

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    protected function trace(...args):void {
        public::trace(args) // access to the public function trace
    }
    public function Main():void 
    {
        trace("hello world")
    }       
}
```

2 - if you can't change the signature assign the original trace into a static var/const so you can use it later :

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    // here save the original trace function
    private static const _trace:Function = trace

    public function trace(...args):void {
        _trace(args) // call the original trace
    }
    public function Main():void 
    {
        trace("hello world")
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I meant the A::trace method to be static (just edited the example code), so the second example would not work, but the first one obviously is the best possible solution