# Access Top Level function when class has a function of the same name

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Ok, in hindsight this does seem to be a silly problem I got myself into and shouldn't have done in the first place.

I have a class `Debug` with a function called trace inside it which puts a `TextField` on the stage and outputs the text.

Now I am trying to get the `Debug.trace()` function to do a "normal" debug trace as well from within side itself.

of course this causes a recursive loop.

I am trying to figure out how I can access the top level separately. I tried using namespaces such as AS3::trace but to no luck.

I know a solution is to rename my function to stop the conflict, but I would like that to be a last resort. So people suggesting a DIFFERENT solution would be helpful.

It is being used in quite alot of places throughout my entire code so replacing it everywhere is going to be a ballache.

Thank you for any "different" solutions to the one above.

Comment: It looks like many people want to call their functions "trace" these days. Way to look for troubles :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324919/how-to-access-top-level-package-in-actionscript

Comment: so your `trace` function isn't static?

Comment: I know you are looking for something different but personally I would bite the bullet and change your trace() function's name to something else. This will eliminate any future problem with it and make your code more maintainable for the next guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `trace()` is a Top Level function and you're 'overriding' it in your Debug class I don't think it's possible to call it in another way.

A possible workaround could be to create a private class beneath your public Debug class. In there you could place a static method you could call which does the actual `trace()` like so:

```
public class Debug
{
    static public function trace(value:*) : void
    {

        /* your textfield code */

        DebugTrace.debugTrace(value);
    }
}

class DebugTrace
{
    public static function debugTrace(value:*) : void
    {
        trace(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: seems @Laurent's comment points to a much better answer. You should use that

Comment: Actually this answer is the best.  The solution @Laurent linked to won't work if your trace method is public.  It says calling "public::trace" will work only if your trace method is private or protected, so if it's public it will still result in the problematic recursion.  The second solution it suggested was saving trace in a static variable, but again it mentions that won't work if your method is static.  So the only working solution for a public static trace function is to have a separate internal class in your ActionScript file as shown above.  IMO.